# Why is my Google Cloud Run server returning a CORS error?

Tags: go, google-cloud-run

I made a backend in go and deployed it using Google Cloud Run. Now I am trying to ping it from my website hosted locally, but then I get a CORS error like

```
type: "cors"
url: "https://abc.a.run.app/do-a"
redirected: false
status: 500
ok: false
statusText: ""
headers: Headers {}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: false
```

These are the headers I set in my http handler function in go.

```
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")
w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type")
```

My handler function is routed like

```
func main() {
    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if port == "" {
        port = "8080"
    }
    http.HandleFunc("/do-a", endpoints.DoA)
    err := http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, nil)
    handle(err)
}
```

Comment: Looks like you have your origin configuration wrong. `w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://localhost:3000")` change localhost:3000 to the URL that you are using `https://....run.app`

Comment: That didn't work. `http://localhost:3000` is the url of my website that is making the call. Using `"*"` didn't work either

Comment: how are you routing to the handler function? can you add that sample code in the question? the reason being if headers for `OPTIONS` requests are not handled properly you might get the CORS error.

Comment: What's the output of an options request `curl -i -X OPTIONS https://abc.a.run.app/do-a` to your backend app?

Comment: `access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type
access-control-allow-origin: *
content-type: application/json
date: Mon, 20 Apr 2020 03:31:52 GMT
server: Google Frontend
content-length: 0
alt-svc: h3-27=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-25=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q048=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000,h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="46,43"`

Comment: There might be another issue in your code then, look in the network tab of your browsers developer tools. I think you'll see the options request, then your call but there's an error in the backend processing that causes the `500 internal server error` which doesn't return the cors headers, leading to a red herring cors issue.

Comment: I think you forgot to set the method header ` 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'GET', `

Answer (score 2):

Please check [this](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#functions_http_cors_auth-python) example from the official documentation:

```
// Package http provides a set of HTTP Cloud Functions samples.
package http

import (
        "fmt"
        "net/http"
)

// CORSEnabledFunctionAuth is an example of setting CORS headers with
// authentication enabled.
// For more information about CORS and CORS preflight requests, see
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Preflight_request.
func CORSEnabledFunctionAuth(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        // Set CORS headers for the preflight request
        if r.Method == http.MethodOptions {
                w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
                w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Authorization")
                w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST")
                w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://example.com")
                w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600")
                w.WriteHeader(http.StatusNoContent)
                return
        }
        // Set CORS headers for the main request.
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
        w.Header().Set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "https://example.com")
        fmt.Fprint(w, "Hello World!")
}
```

From the code you posted I can not tell if you check for the preflight request and set the `Access-Control-Allow-Methods` header.